# How to properly sub class React native webview to disable the context menu on selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I need to disable the default context menu, that pops up when some text is selected in the react-native-webView.

I forked the library and added a new **`MyWebView.h`** and **`MyWebView.m`** files to try and disable the selection action.

```c
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```

Then inside **`RNCWebView.m`** file, I made the following changes:

1. In the `implementation` block of RNCWebView, I instantiated my custom webview as

   ```c
     @implementation RNCWebView

     {
        MJRWebView *_webView;
        (other code here)
     }
   ```
2. Then inside `initWithFrame`, I am doing the following:

   ```c
    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
     {
        if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        super.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _webView = [[MJRWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        (other props)
   ```

The selection got disabled, but other props like `onMessage` and `injectJavascript` stopped working. Is this the correct way of disabling the context menu ?

Answer (score 0):

The `RNCWebView` is a `WKUIDelegate`, as below from declaration

```
@interface RNCWebView () <WKUIDelegate, ...
```

so you just need to create a subclass of `RNCWebView` and add the only following

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView contextMenuConfigurationForElement:(WKContextMenuElementInfo *)elementInfo 
   completionHandler:(void (^)(UIContextMenuConfiguration * _Nullable configuration))completionHandler
{
   completionHandler(nil);
}
```

and use your subclass.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi.
So, there is no need of
```- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}```

Comment: @Asperi Can you please elaborate what you meant by using subclass ? What I did previously was replace code inside RNCWebview.m itself with my custom subclass of WKWebView. Did you mean all of that is not necessary ?

Comment: Subclass? Hmm... `@interface MyRNCWebView: RNCWebView`. No, all of that not needed. At least to disable context menu.

Comment: Actually what I did in was MyWebView.h was `@interface MJRWebView :WKWebView` and not from `RNCWebView` as I was modifying the code within the package `react-native-webview`, which itself extends WKWebView. Then I used it inside `RNCWebView.m`. I don't know if I can use `@interface MyRNCWebView: RNCWebView` within the same package.

Comment: Ok, then just add callback from answer into `@implementation RNCWebView` of RNCWebView.m. And don't forget to remove all your previous modifications - they are not needed for this purpose.

Comment: Add 
```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView contextMenuConfigurationForElement:(WKContextMenuElementInfo *)elementInfo
   completionHandler:(void (^)(UIContextMenuConfiguration * _Nullable configuration))completionHandler
   completionHandler(nil);
}
``` to the @implementation?